# Parenthesis Matching in C using Stack

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I am trying to match Parenthesis in C using Stack Data Structure. I have made some stack operation functions and parenthesisMatch() function to return me 0 or 1 based on whether the stack is empty or not.
But I don't get the output.
This is what the source code for the problem looks like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Stack definition 
struct stack
{
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;//for storing characters.
};
int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr);
int isFull(struct stack *ptr);
void push(struct stack* ptr, char val);
char pop(struct stack* ptr);
int parenthesisMatch(char * exp);
int main()
{
    char *exp = "((8)(*--$$9))";
    // Check if stack is empty
    if(parenthesisMatch(exp)){
        printf("The parenthesis is matching");
    }
    else{
        printf("The parenthesis is not matching");
    }
    return 0;
}
 
int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr){
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
 
int isFull(struct stack *ptr){
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
 
void push(struct stack* ptr, char val){
    if(isFull(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Overflow! Cannot push %d to the stack\n", val);
    }
    else{
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
}
 
char pop(struct stack* ptr){
    if(isEmpty(ptr)){
        printf("Stack Underflow! Cannot pop from the stack\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        char val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top--;
        return val;
    }
}
 
int parenthesisMatch(char * exp){
    // Create and initialize the stack
    struct stack* sp;
    sp->size = 100; //set the size of stack 'sp' to 100
    sp->top = -1;  //Empty stack
    sp->arr = (char *)malloc(sp->size * sizeof(char)); //DMA for character
 
    //Do the push and Pop operation
    for (int i = 0; exp[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(exp[i]=='('){
            push(sp, '(');
        }
        else if(exp[i]==')'){
            if(isEmpty(sp)){
                return 0;
            }
            pop(sp); 
        }
    }
 
    if(isEmpty(sp)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    
}
```

Complier Message
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUwnO.png)

To view Output ScreenShot
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvMLz.png)

Comment: Are you using the stack as an excersise? Otherwise this solution seems like overkill.

Comment: You usually use a signed integer and +1 for open, and -1 for close.  If the value goes negative you have a problem.  If it value is not 0 when done processing the data there is a mismatch.

Comment: The error in your code is the 'sp' variable, it's not initialized. The easiest solution is to make it a 'struct stack sp;' instead of a pointer.